# what is val_sample_weight in keras?

Tags: neural-network, keras, deep-learning

What does the val_sample_weight option in model.fit do?
I understand that it enables calculating weighted matrices (weighted accuracy for example) for validation set, but does (and if so, how?) it effect the calculation of the loss for the validation set?
Because I get different results for the loss of the validation set when using it vs not using it.

I use class_weight in both scenarios.

In the Keras website under model.fit it doesn't really say.